# Spring Security Authentication UserDetailsService Implementation class not being invoked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm trying to migrate from Spring XML based configuration to Pure Java Configuration, I have configured all the configuration files, but when I try to enter the username and password in login page, it redirects me back to the login page again. I believe the userServiceImpl method is not being invoked because the control is not going there. 
Here, I have autowired userServiceImpl method which is implementing UserDetailsService of spring security core credentials.

```
package com.lw.sms.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.lw.sms.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import com.lw.sms.UserServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Order(1000)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Value("${jdbc.dialect}")
    String jdbcDialect;

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    String jdbcDriverClassName;

    @Value("${jdbc.databaseurl}")
    String jdbcDatabaseurl;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    String jdbcusername;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    String jdbcPassword;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;


    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        logger.info("configure auth");
        auth.userDetailsService(userServiceImpl);
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("configure http");
        http.httpBasic().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("employeeId")
                .passwordParameter("password").successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true)

                .loginProcessingUrl("j_spring_security_check")

                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

                .and().sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/logout").maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).expiredUrl("/logout");
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        logger.info("sessionRegistry");
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
        builder.scanPackages("com.lw.sms").addProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean hibernateSessionFactory() {
        logger.info("sessionFactory");
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.lw.sms");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        logger.info("dataSource");
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcDatabaseurl);
        dataSource.setUsername(jdbcusername);
        dataSource.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        logger.info("transactionManager");
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return htm;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        logger.info("hibernateProperties");
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", jdbcDialect);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "sms");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler Code is attached below

```
package com.lw.sms;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.lw.sms.constants.Constants;
import com.lw.sms.user.entities.EmployeeEntity;
import com.lw.sms.user.entities.EmployeePermissionsEntity;
import com.lw.sms.user.service.UserManagementService;
import com.lw.sms.util.QueryBuilder;


@Component("customAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.class);

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionInfo")
    private SessionInfo sessionInfo;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userManagementServiceImpl")
    private UserManagementService userManagementService;

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        handle(request, response);
    }

    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

            if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
                EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = (EmployeeEntity) principal;
                setSessionInformationForEmployee(employeeEntity);
            }

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            return;
        }
        startServices();
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/dashboard");
    }

    /**
     * @param employeeEntity 
     * 
     */
    private void setSessionInformationForEmployee(EmployeeEntity employeeEntity) {
        try {
            WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication().getDetails();
            userManagementService.updateLoginInfo(employeeEntity.getUsername(), details.getRemoteAddress());
            // setting session information
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Exception while set Session Information For Employee :" + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

    private void startServices() {
        logger.info("Starting Services..");
        try {
            String domainName = httpServletRequest.getScheme() + "://" + httpServletRequest.getServerName();
            if (httpServletRequest.getServerPort() != 0) {
                domainName += ":" + httpServletRequest.getServerPort();
            }
            domainName += httpServletRequest.getContextPath();
            Constants.domainName = domainName + "/resources";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in start services :"+ ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }

    }

    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }

    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }
}
```

UserServiceImpl Code is attached below

```
package com.lw.sms;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.lw.sms.user.dao.UserManagementDAO;
import com.lw.sms.user.entities.EmployeeEntity;

@Service("userServiceImpl")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userManagementDAOImpl")
    private UserManagementDAO userManagementDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = userManagementDAO.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (employeeEntity == null) {
            ContractorEntity contractorEntity = userManagementDAO.loadUserByUsernameContractor(username);
            if(contractorEntity == null)
                throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Invalid Username or Password");
        }
        if(!employeeEntity.isEnabled())
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Employee Disabled");
        return employeeEntity;
    }

}
```

Global Exception Handler Code:

```
package com.lw.sms;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Controller
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3699167829164697594L;


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CustomExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    public ModelAndView handleLoginExceptions(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,Exception exception) {
        logger.info("Handling exception time error"+ exception.getMessage());
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpSessionRequiredException.class)
    public String handleSessionExpired() {
        logger.info("session-expired");
        return "logout";
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { MissingServletRequestParameterException.class,
            ServletRequestBindingException.class, TypeMismatchException.class,
            HttpMessageNotReadableException.class,
            MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
            MissingServletRequestPartException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Bad Request")
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject handle400Exception(Exception ex,HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.error("400 Exception" + ex.getMessage());
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("status", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        jsonObject.put("success", false);
        jsonObject.put("message", ex.getMessage());
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        return jsonObject;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class, })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Not Found")
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean handle404Exception(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("404 Exception" + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));
        return false;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class,
            HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, reason = "Not Supported")
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean handle405Exception(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("405 Exception" + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));
        return false;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { HttpMessageNotWritableException.class,
            ConversionNotSupportedException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "Internal Server Error")
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean handle500Exception(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("500 Exception" + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));
        return false;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
    public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.info("*****************************************************");
        logger.error("Exception: " + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.info("*****************************************************");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("logout");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

This is my HomeController.

```
package com.lw.sms;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.lw.sms.master.service.MasterDataService;
import com.lw.sms.user.entities.EmployeeEntity;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller("homeController")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("masterDataServiceImpl")
    private MasterDataService masterDataService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionInfo")
    private SessionInfo sessionInfo;

    @GetMapping(value = { "/home", "/", "login" })
    public ModelAndView home() {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "dashboard")
    public ModelAndView dashboard() {

        EmployeeEntity user = sessionInfo.getEmployeeEntity();
        return new ModelAndView("dashboard", "userDetails", user);
    }

    // Logout page
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    @GetMapping(value = "logout")
    public String logout() {
        return "logout";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try adding the successForwardUrl also as below.

```
 http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/dashboard").access("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
        .antMatchers("/j_spring_security_check").access("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("employeeId").passwordParameter("password")
        .successForwardUrl("/dashboard").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true).failureForwardUrl("/loginfailed")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionFixation().none()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied").and().csrf().disable();
```

Comment: Hey Sujay, now the control is going to UserServiceImpl method and also returning successfully, but after the return, the control is not going to customAuthenticationSuccessHandler, its getting caught in a @ControllerAdvice Class with 406. Any idea why?

Comment: Is the ControllerAdvice class written in the project?

Comment: This is like the Global Exception Handler of the whole project if we miss handling an exception anywhere, it gets handled here.
I've updated the code here. The control lands in 405 Exception method.

Comment: Since you are getting method not supported could you please check the controller method which has the request mapping /dashboard which is the success url. It should be a get request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198755/discussion-between-shiva-kumar-and-sujay-mohan).

Comment: is your issue fixed. if yes, could you please post the answer.

Comment: Hey Sujay, I have changed the AppInitializer code by using `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and Spring security by using `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` with reference from [this](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/) Article. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the error. 
I had to configure a new bean in SecurityConfig file.

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;

        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userServiceImpl);
            authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return authenticationProvider;
        }
```